# Chasing the number of smth

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, sentence

I am not sure if I use this sentence correctly and the idea is clear.

> I am not chasing the number of projects done, but the number of
>   well-done projects instead.

My idea is to say that I am not trying to do as many projects as can (time restricted only), but I am trying to do as many well-done projects as I can.

Please let me know how it sounds. Maybe it could be improved. Please let me know if I've made any mistakes in the sentence or in this question.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what *chasing* is supposed to mean here.

Comment: @Barmar I have just update the question, please have a look.

Comment: If you  have  to explain what you are trying to say, then the idea _is not clear_.

Comment: 'chasing' is just too metaphorical. if you were writing poetry, it'd be fine, but for a progress report it's on the other side of making sense.

Comment: Quality over quantity. Or 'I am not seeking the completion of the most projects, but the satisfactory completion of the most projects'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**maximize**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/maximize) is a possible word here.

> Make as large or great as possible.

Example:

> I am not trying to maximize the number of projects done, but the number of well-done projects instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, could you please explain the meaning of "chasing", it is more about physical action (one person chases another ?). Because I have heard several times in different songs something like "Chasing dreams .."

Comment: It is often used as a metaphor.

Comment: but as I can understand, in my case this is not an acceptable variant ?

Comment: The problem is that chasing needs a direct object. You might chase a *way* to maximize the number of well-done projects. But you don't chase a number.

Comment: @HelloMufecayo - ***chasing*** has the idea of “trying to catch “ in it.  You are not trying to catch a number of projects.